# @throws in Scala does not allow calling Java to catch correct exception type

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, exception, scala-ide

I have some Scala code like this:

```
class Callee {
  @throws(classOf[MyCheckedException])
  def doStuff() {
  }
}
```

Calling it from Java like so:

```
public class Caller {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // this won't compile; the Java compiler complains that the catch block is unreachable
    // however without the catch block, it complains "unhandled exception MyCheckedException"
    try {
      new Callee().doStuff();
    }
    catch (MyCheckedException e) {

    }
  }
}
```

Removing the catch block results in an error from the Java compiler saying 'unhandled exception type MyCheckedException'. Adding the catch block for MyCheckedException results in the compiler complaining about the catch block being unreachable, because the exception is never thrown.

If I catch Exception and do an instanceOf, I can trap the correct exception coming out of doStuff, but I thought the @throws annotation was supposed to generate the right bytecode for the proper catch block to work. Am I wrong, or is there a bug here?

For the record, this is with Scala 2.9.2 and Java 1.6.

**Edit:** It compiles fine invoking javac/scalac using sbt from the command line. The error is only apparent during compile-as-you-type in Eclipse, which suggests the bug is in either the Eclipse Java Compiler or some part of the IDE. Can others reproduce it this way? I am using Eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: help us to help you ,show some code

Comment: Cannot reproduce, can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Full classes now included above

Comment: Still cannot reproduce on javac 1.6.0_24, scalac 2.9.2. How do you compile it?

Comment: See above - the problem is only apparent during compile-as-you-type from Eclipse. I had assumed that javac on the command line would match this, but I was wrong.

Comment: @DavidNorth Have you attempted to do a Clean and Rebuild on the project? Sometimes that appeases Eclipse.

Comment: Clean and Rebuild doesn't help here. Nor does changing the build order in the scala workspace parameters.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell You are correct, I just tried it myself. I think you're right its a bug.

Comment: For future reference, this issue has been *fixed* (https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide/commit/055a81cd3fe792e4327668791888c30cf04793f5). The fix is already available with both [Scala IDE 2.0.x and Helium nightlies](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html). Furthermore, it will be included in the next Scala IDE 2.0.2 maintenace release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can reproduce this on Helios with 2.9.1. It is a bug in the presentation compiler, and you should raise it as a bug on http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets.

Comment: Thanks. It may or may not be a duplicate of http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000707-java-editor-doesn-t-grok-@throws-annotation-on-scala-traits, but I'll raise it separately for now

Comment: @David North I'm pretty sure it is a duplicate of the ticket you linked. Maybe you can add your test case to the same ticket.

Comment: Ended up raising http://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets/1001005-@throws-on-scala-method-confuses-the-java-editor-on-calling-code

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, this issue has been fixed (https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide/commit/055a81cd3fe792e4327668791888c30cf04793f5). The fix is already available with both [Scala IDE 2.0.x and Helium nightlies](http://scala-ide.org/download/nightly.html). 
Furthermore, it will be included in the next Scala IDE 2.0.2 maintenace release.

(sorry for the additional noise, but I realized that having an answer was more visible than a simple comment)